# how to take string from this type of data?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, string

```
a:2:{i:3;s:16:"GLS PARTICULIERS";i:1;s:16:"GLS PARTICULIERS";}
```

I have this type of data in multiples rows. What I want is just to take out the name in " " that's it I don't want the whole data. Does anyone know about this? I am using PHP.

Comment: use the PHP `explode` method to extract the required data.

Comment: I used it but no luck

Comment: Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/function.unserialize.php

Comment: @HasaanAli this is serialised data. `unserialize()` should be used here

Comment: solved it by doing unserialize() thanks dude you have got good eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this as said by @Majid and @ADyson

```
$txt = 'a:2:{i:3;s:16:"GLS PARTICULIERS";i:1;s:16:"GLS PARTICULIERS";}';
$php_array = unserialize($txt);
var_dump($php_array);
```

`php_array` will dump all the array and you can see how to fetch that data.

Answer (score 1):

Try php function unserialize. Assign this data to a variable and then put that variable inside the unserialize function.

```
$php_array = unserialize($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

$data = 'a:2:{i:3;s:4:"Name";i:1;s:4:"Name";}';
print_r(unserialize($data));
solved this by doing something like this